# How to allow resubmission of file uploads after failure with Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I have a file upload form that uses Dropzone.js to upload files to my server. A user can upload up to 5 fivles at once, but I have a unique condition I'm dealing with: if any single file errors out on the server end (over the maximum size, wrong mime-type, wrong file type, etc), I need none of the files to be added to my database. This is not a problem.

What I am having a problem with is the client side handling of it. Why is it when I get a response from the server, I can no longer upload files again by clicking "submit" (the element of which is bound to an event handler, as seen below)?

```
        Dropzone.options.uploadedFilesDropzone = {
              autoProcessQueue: false,
              maxFilesize: 1024, //MB
              addRemoveLinks: true,
              uploadMultiple: true,
              parallelUploads: 5,
              maxFiles: 5,
              init: function() {

                var uploadedFilesDropzone = this;

                $('#submit').on('click', function() {
                    uploadedFilesDropzone.processQueue();

                    uploadedFilesDropzone.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                        // Handle the responseText here. For example, add the text to the preview element:
                        console.log(files);
                        console.log(response.errors[0]);
                        $.each(files, function(index, file) {
                            // no errors
                            if (response.errors[index].length == 0) {

                            } else {
                                file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-error');
                            }
                        })
                     });
                });
              }
        }
```

Comment: In what way does clicking submit fail? Does nothing happen? Do you get an error? Can you upload more if there are no errors?

Comment: This dropbox issue may help,
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/717

Answer (score 13):

Files are removed from the Dropzone queue once `processQueue()` is called. You can no longer upload the files by clicking submit because there are no files in the queue.

You need to add each file back into the queue after the response has been received.

If there is an error with the files server side it is best to set the status code of the response to something other than 200 so that you can override the Dropzone error listener.

```
    this.on("error", function(file, errorMessage) {
        $.each(dropZone.files, function(i, file) {
            file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED
        });

        $.each(message, function(i, item) {
            $("#dropzoneErrors .errors ul").append("<li>" + message[i] + "</li>")
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just as a solution I have been looking for. Thanks so much